# Importing Redux into my ASP.NET MVC Project using RequreJS, TypeScript (Error: Script error for "redux", needed by...)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript, requirejs

I'm trying to get a basic example of the Redux state library working with my ASP.NET MVC application with TypeScript and RequireJS.

It is a very simple application, I've created a new ASP.NET MVC Project, stripped a lot out of it so that I only have my node modules (Redux, RequireJS) and the script that I want to execute (Question.ts) below, which complies to Question.js.

**Question.ts**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/node_modules/",
    paths: {
        "redux": "redux/dist/redux.js"
    }
});

import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
const ADD_SELECTED_ANSWER = 'ADD_SELECTED_ANSWER';

function addSelectedAnswer(selectedQuestionId: number) {
    return { type: ADD_SELECTED_ANSWER, selectedQuestionId }
}

function selectedAnswers(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_SELECTED_ANSWER:

            var nextState = state;

            nextState.push(state);

            return nextState;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

var questionApp = combineReducers({
    SelectedAnswers: selectedAnswers
});

var store = createStore(questionApp);

// Log the initial state
console.log(store.getState());

// Every time the state changes, log it
// Note that subscribe() returns a function for unregistering the listener
let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
    console.log(store.getState())
);

store.dispatch(addSelectedAnswer(100));
```

TypeScript compiles this to the following (**Question.js**):

```
define(["require", "exports", "redux"], function (require, exports, redux_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "./",
        paths: {
            "redux": "/node_modules/redux/dist/redux.js"
        }
    });
    var ADD_SELECTED_ANSWER = 'ADD_SELECTED_ANSWER';
    function addSelectedAnswer(selectedQuestionId) {
        return { type: ADD_SELECTED_ANSWER, selectedQuestionId: selectedQuestionId };
    }
    function selectedAnswers(state, action) {
        if (state === void 0) { state = []; }
        switch (action.type) {
            case ADD_SELECTED_ANSWER:
                var nextState = state;
                nextState.push(state);
                return nextState;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    var questionApp = redux_1.combineReducers({
        SelectedAnswers: selectedAnswers
    });
    var store = redux_1.createStore(questionApp);
    // Log the initial state
    console.log(store.getState());
    // Every time the state changes, log it
    // Note that subscribe() returns a function for unregistering the listener
    var unsubscribe = store.subscribe(function () {
        return console.log(store.getState());
    });
    store.dispatch(addSelectedAnswer(100));
});
//# sourceMappingURL=Question.js.map
```

I am navigating to the Home controller, just `http://localhost:50830/`, in order to execute this basic script that should import Redux and execute a basic dispatch of a Redux method to modify the state.

Upon running, I'm getting the error below:

> require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "redux", needed by: Question

No matter the configuration that I have provided to the `import` or to the RequireJS `basePath` or `paths` configuration, I can't seem to get TypeScript to compile in a way that allows it to find my the Redux module.

The view is simply:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

Please execute my Redux!

@section scripts
{
    <script data-main="/Scripts/Question.js" src="~/node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
}
```

This is the structure of the solution:

[image: Solution structure]

How can I get TypeScript to compile my `Question.ts` file so that it can load in `redux.js`?

Here's a link to the solution file if that helps someone to help me to figure this out: https://s3.amazonaws.com/helpme123123/Redux+Playground.zip

Comment: `baseUrl` of `node_modules` looks suspect. You need to tell RequireJS where redux is at any rate and you are not doing that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I just tried changing it to another configuration, I've updated the question above.  Perhaps I'm still not telling it where Redux lives.

Comment: I am able to navigate to the Redux.js file by going to `http://localhost:50830/node_modules/redux/dist/redux.js` and the script is executing at `http://localhost:50830/` so I don't understand why it can't find it :(

Comment: I think it needs to be `baseUrl: "/"` and `"redux": "node_modules/redux/dist/redux.js"`

Comment: Sadly that configuration isn't working either. I tried combinations with trailing slashes and trailing `./` too just now and it still doesn't pick it up.  Thanks for any further assistance.  I've dumped the solution on S3 and included a link. Any help solving this is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't suppose you have any more idea? :(

Comment: Sorry, It has been a while since I used RequireJS. I primarily use SystemJS now (or Webpack when forced to), so the specifics of RequireJS configuration are not at the forefront of my mind.

Comment: Got it working and posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I missed the obvious pretty hard when I looked at this the first time. I will attempt to both explain what is wrong, and how to fix it.

The first problem is that you `main`, `"Scripts/Question"` is a module (a module is any file containing a top level `import` or `export` statement) that depends on redux. A module's dependencies must be resolved before it itself can execute. But this module contains the RequireJS configuration needed to resolve them in the first place.

The transpiled `Scripts/Question.js` is

```
define(["require", "exports", "redux"], function (require, exports, redux_1) {
    "use strict";
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "node_modules/"
    });
    var ADD_SELECTED_ANSWER = 'ADD_SELECTED_ANSWER';
    function addSelectedAnswer(selectedQuestionId) {
        return { type: ADD_SELECTED_ANSWER, selectedQuestionId: selectedQuestionId };
    }
    // etc.
});
```

And that is our primary problem. `require.config` will only ever be called after Question.js is loaded. But in order for that to happen RequireJS clearly needs to resolve and load redux.

In order to fix this, we need to configure the loader, RequireJS, before we load any modules that depend on that configuration.

So first, we move the `require.config` call into a new file, say `Scripts/Main.js`, with the following content

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        "redux": "node_modules/redux/dist/redux"
    }
});

require(["Scripts/Question"], () => {
    console.log("bootstrapped");
});
```

A few things to note about this file are

1. It sets the baseUrl to `"/"`, that is above both `Scripts` *and* `node_modules`. This is important because we need to load code from both locations.
2. It maps redux explicitly. Loaders like RequireJS and SystemJS are browser oriented. They do not assume or rely on server-side JavaScript conventions such as "deps are in a folder called node modules and have entry points specified in package.json" (they are explicit and I like that)
3. After configuring the loader it invokes it with the actually primary entry module. IIRC there is a more elegant way to do this but I do not remember it at the moment.

Now we simply need to change `index.cshtml` to load `Scripts/Main.js` instead of `Scripts/Question.js`

```
<script data-main="/Scripts/Main.js" src="~/node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

And remove the `require.config` call from `Scripts/Question.js`

Comment: Aluan, Thanks so much for taking the time to take a look at this and for leading me to how to correct it.  If I could award more points then I really would!  I started boiling the code down to just a few files and I came to realise that having "require" as a dependency of my code was indeed wrong!  Thank you Thank you Thank you.  Hopefully this question will be useful for anyone else trying to get going with Typescript, RequireJS and other things.

Comment: Glad I could help.